# Does React libraries and npm modules reside at client side (browser side) along with actual js code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client-side

Is React and ReactDOM libraries reside in running html page(single page) at browser?

Are other js libraries (installed in npm_modules) are also reside in running HTML page at browser ?

Or all above libraries and actual code (programmers) converted to single/multiple JS files and each time when SPA page loads it has all these files but in converted(bundled) manner?

My understanding is React is client side library that means it is present at html page while page is running in browser.

Apology for very basic questions but these questions in my mind many days and couldn't find satisfactory post or I missed.

Comment: So the simple answer to your question is yes.

Comment: in Client Side rendering in ReactJS, your application is downloaded as `.js bundle`  and is injected in runtime into `<div id="root`>`. To let this `.js bundle` to function properly, it needs the supporting npm libraries and hence they are already fetched along with your `.js bundle`. So yes everything should be available at client side (browser side)

Comment: @RohitKhanna : So In browser there 5 ReactJS application open then 5 times all the respective required dependancies ( libraries like React, ReactDom, loadash, redux, so on ... ) will be loaded ?

Comment: @NitinDaphale, If not loaded each time, dont you think there will be a conflict because there is a possibility, each of these five applications use different versions of libraries (may be conflicting versions, if app is quite old) and one of them may start to behave weirdly just because browser caches the library of a different version due to parallel running app?

Comment: @RohitKhanna: Thanks , that makes sense.